# Simplest way to insert variables into SQL Stored Procedure using Python?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I have a stored SQL procedure I would like to generalize. This involves passing the Table name, a start time, and an end time through as variables, so one doesn't have to edit the procedure every time. I'm trying to use basic python variables to prompt the user. (Start = int(input("Enter Start Time: "))
I just haven't found a simple way to do this. I've used 'execute sp_execute_external_scripts' and have been seeing if Pyodbc is the right tool for this, but nothing so far has worked, and I didn't fully understand the MS documentation/tutorial for creating a wrapper. So what is the easiest way to prompt the user for input that can be injected into a procedure as a variable? I feel like I'm missing something very simple here.

Upon reading comments here, my original method is overbroad and would require dynamicsql, which I'm not automatically opposed to, but it seems safer to create procedures for individual tables. So I should only need to push Start, End and ChunkSize as integer variables into the procedure.

SOLVED: I got the desired results by writing a small python program using pyodbc. Thank you for the help and gentle nudging away from my original, naive idea.

```
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                            'Server=CROWN;'
                            'Database=ControlInformation;'
                            'Trusted_Connection=yes;')


cursor = connection.cursor()

Start = int(input("Enter Start Time: "))
End = int(input("Enter End Time: "))
ChunkSize = int(input("Enter # of files to delete at once: "))
cursor.execute('exec PurgeCurrencyExchangeRates @start = %d, @end = %d, 
@ChunkSize = %d' %(Start, End, ChunkSize))
cursor.commit(), 
connection.close()
```

SQL stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UserInput 
@r int = 1,
@Start bigint = 0, 
@End bigint = 0,
@TableName varchar(40) = 'CurrencyExchangeRates',
@ChunkSize int = 10000,
@ColumnName varchar(40) = 'Timestamp'

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

while @r > 0
    delete top(@ChunkSize)
        ControlInformation.dbo.@TableName
        where @ColumnName > @Start and @ColumnName < @End

    set @r = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Comment: Why are you creating a generic "delete all data from table x" procedure? You can't parameterize table or column names so this would require dynamic sql. But again....why??? This is sort of like creating a generic delete method in a programming language where you have to pass in the object name.

Comment: Dynamically passing in the table name suggests you're violating the usual rules of relational database design. That should be a column in a single table that partitions the data.

Comment: the intent is NOT to delete all data from table X. I'm trying to delete a large amount of rows between two dateranges. Additionally, I'm chunking it because it's too much data to delete at once, and interrupts other processes our business is running on the database.

Comment: The chunking part I understand. But you are making a procedure that can delete data from any table. This is a sign that either you are trying to make it too generic or your architecture is denormalized (or perhaps both).

Comment: Okay @SeanLange, I'm going to slightly alter how I'm trying to go about this. Instead of overgeneralizing, should I make a procedure for each table to be deleted? (getting rid of TableName and ColumnName) That's easy to do, but i still have the underlying issue of pushing Start, End and ChunkSize as variables and not static parameters. User input is the main goal here.

Comment: That is how I would proceed. Just like a programming language we want our procedures to be specific to the item at hand.

Comment: @SeanLange with that change in mind, avoiding the pitfalls of overgeneralizing and dynamicsql,is there a simple way to have a user input values for the 3 remaining integer variables?

Comment: I can't even spell python, let along be qualified to answer how to capture user input. But the procedure below from David Browne is a great example of how the sql should look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored procedure should be something like:

```
use CurrencyExchangeRates
go
CREATE PROCEDURE PurgeCurrencyExchangeRates 
@Start bigint = 0, 
@End bigint = 0,
@ChunkSize int = 10000
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @r int = 1;


    while @r > 0
    begin
        delete top(@ChunkSize)
            from dbo.CurrencyExchangeRates
            where [Timestamp] >= @Start and [Timestamp] < @End

        set @r = @@ROWCOUNT
    end

end
```

Comment: Thank you for the cleanup of the procedure, it seems that trying to generalize over all tables is bad form. But how do I integrate start, end, and chunksize as variables that the user can enter? I'm aware that SQL cannot do that, which is why I'm trying to write a small python wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need in python:

```
Start = int(input("Enter Start Time: "))
sql = 'exec UserInput @start =?'
cursor.execute(sql, Start)
cursor.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make the table name *dynamic* then you'll need to use *dynamic SQL*, like so:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE DeleteFrom 
    @tableName sysname ='Table0'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000);
    SET @sql = N'DELETE TOP (1) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName);
    EXEC(@sql);
END
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to sql inection. At the very least you should wrap the table name with QUOTENAME.